# jQuery event get a value from TR ID from table

Tags: jquery, events

HTML:

```
<table class="tdiv" id="tnv">
    <tr>
       <td id="isrdata1">1</td> <-- Need get a value -->
       <td>Something bla bla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="isrdata2">2</td>
       <td>Something bla bla</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
        $('#tnv').find('tr').click( function(){
            var isrdata = ($(this).index()+1);

            console.log(isrdata);


        });
```

How to get `#isrdata` value from `tr` ?

Comment: `id` in HTML must be unique

Comment: Note: The id isrdata is mentioned twice.

Comment: If a click on a ROW I get properly Table ID. But, how get a Id name from TR?

Comment: The best way to store data on an element is to use `data-` ...
So use `data-something` to store and get it with `attr()`

Comment: based on all the answers that differ wildley you could probably be a little more clear on what value you are actually trying to get, the value stored in the ID attribute or the contents of the element with the id of `isrdata` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ditch the call to `.find()`:

```
$('#tnv tr').click(function () {
    var isrdata = ($(this).index() + 1);
    console.log(isrdata);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ApQPT/)**

Answer (score 1):

As noted above change isrdata from the id to class then

I would use a each loop

```
$(["#tnv .isrdata"]).each(function (i) 
{
        console.log($(this).text());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
$('#tnv').find('tr').click( function(){
    var isrdata = $(this).find('td:first').attr('id');
    console.log(isrdata);

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a8yNH/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#tnv tr").on("click", function(event){
    var isrdata = $(this).children('td.isrdata').text();
    console.log(isrdata);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get ID of element

```
var idName = $("elem").attr("id");
```

After find dy ID some element:

```
$("#"+idName).html();
```

If you want get content of element:

```
$("elem").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
<table class="tdiv" id="tnv">
    <tr>
       <td class="isrdata">1</td>
       <td>Something bla bla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="isrdata">2</td>
       <td>Something bla bla</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
    $('#tnv').find('tr').click( function(){
        var isrdata = $(this).find(".isrdata").text();
        console.log(isrdata);
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fVExZ/1/)

I replaced the duplicate ID's with a class instead. On the click of a `tr` within `#tnv` I find the element with a class of `isrdata` and then pull the text out of that.